# How to sync iCal of iPhone Os and google calendar?

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar

I have made event Calendar using EKEventKit,
Now I want to add my iphone ical event to google calendar and vise-versa.
Is it Possible to do this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I can't offer sample code I can offer a high-level solution.

Google Calendar has a public API available [here](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html).
Google is also kind enough to offer code to log into Google services [here](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/).

If you're familiar with JSON (or you search through stackoverflow) you'll see how you can send events to and from Google Calendar.
Best of luck!